# アプリケーション名が日本語のアプリをAppleScriptで起動させたい

Tags: macos, applescript

AppleScriptで”ワイヤレス診断.app”を起動させようとしていますが、うまく起動せず困っております。
OSはYosemite10.10.2、スクリプトエディタはバージョン 2.7 (176)です。

書いたコード：

```
tell application "System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/ワイヤレス診断.app"
    activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "6" using {command down}
end tell
```

エラー：

```
error "application \"System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/ワイヤレス診断.app\" を取り出すことはできません。"
 number -1728 from current application
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ローカライズされていないアプリ名なら、名称だけでOKです。

```
tell application "Wireless Diagnostics"
    activate
end tell
```

「本来」のアプリ名は、「情報を見る」で調べられます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

余談：
基本、AppleScriptは、UNIX式のパス書式（/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications...）を使いません。使うときは、「POSIX file」とします。

```
tell application "Finder"
    set filePath to POSIX file "/Users/(username)/Desktop/info.png"
    open filePath
end tell
```

Comment: なるほど、アプリ名だけでよかったのですね。
確認方法もそちらのほうがはるかに簡単です。
どうもありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

ローカライズ用のファイルを参照して
OS が「ワイヤレス診断」と表示しているので、もとの英語のアプリ名で叩けば起動する。

Finder からワイヤレス診断.appを右クリックし、「パッケージの内容を表示」し、
InfoPlistを開く。

”Wireless Diagnostics”という名前だと分かるので、下記のようにコードを修正。

```
tell application "System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Wireless Diagnostics.app"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "6" using {command down}  
end tell
```